# Debugging with specific browser in Visual Studio 2015 not possible anymore?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2013 it was possible to start debugging with a specific browser:
 [image]

I' missing this functionality in Visual Studio 2015

[image]

Is there somewhre an option to bring it back? (Browse with... starts the browser but doesn't start debugging)

**UPDATE**

It seems that the the browser selection is not gone (thanks Gregor for your answer), but however something wrong with my installation.
I've tried to do a Reset (Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings) but that didn't help as well.

Anyone else having a solution how to bring the browser seletion back ?

**UPDATE 2**

It seems that the missing Items only affect Windows 7 (64bit?) Users. Can someone else confirm that?

**UPDATE 3**

If you have the same problem please report it to Microsoft here
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1599622/debugging-with-specific-browser-in-visual-studio-2015-not-possible-anymore

Comment: I added a browser in "Browse with" http://pho.to/9at8a, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @feco not really because it just starts the browser but not the debugger.

Comment: is the diagnostic tool on the right side missing or am I missing something else? :S

Comment: It is but you've started debugging first, then "Browse with" or am I wrong? :-) with VS 2015 i could do that at once by selecting the browser name. that started the debugger and the browser.

Comment: Which Version of Win7 do you have? Do you have installed 32-Bit Versions of the browser?

Comment: What happens, if you click "Start"?

Comment: I have Windows 7 Enterprise. If I press Start it starts the Default Browser. Funny thing is in VS 2013 it works... I have the browser selection as per screenshot. I've also asked a friend that works in another company. He has Win 7 as well and doesn't see the browser selection. So I'm starting to believe that this is a OS issue. Can anybody else confirm that?

Comment: Is your Win7 Enterprise 64 Bit?

Comment: Yes it is. But I don't believe that's the reason. Because again in VS 2013 the items are there.

Comment: And the Items in VS 2013 work as expected? Do you tried WebSocket4Net?

Comment: Yes the work as expected. I asked a developer from another company that doesn't have the same machine restriction that we have in our company. he's also running win 7 and doesn't see the stuff in VS 2015 as well. Another mate from my company that runs another OS have the items.  So to me it seems a VS 2015 Bug to me. Would be nice if someone else that runs VS 2015 on Win 7 would report the same issue.

Comment: Same problem here. Installed clean Windows 10 Pro and VStudio 2015 Community Edition. Chrome 44 is my default browser.

Comment: Hi @NickD if you don't mind vote up here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1599622/debugging-with-specific-browser-in-visual-studio-2015-not-possible-anymore

Comment: Having multiple startup projects will make the browser selector go away. But you can set a single startup project as the only startup, and then set the preferred browser under "Start" - It will then remember this setting when going back to mulitple startup projects.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you running into the same problems as me, try the follwoing:

Select `Browse with...` and then set another browser als default. Afterwards the "Start"  gets replaced with the specific Browser Name and all Browsers are available.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm having this issue in VS2015 Update 2 using asp.net 5 update 1.  I'd love to get it fixed but don't understand your solution.  Select browse from where?

Comment: Your screenshots helped me realize that I didn't have that option displayed in the tool bar.  For others missing the option like me, go to "Add or Remove Buttons" on the end of the "Standard" tool bar and check the "Debug Target" menu choice.  This will provide the drop down in the tool bar for displaying the browser to use and also the "Browse With..." menu choice.

Answer (score 15):

I just had a very similar issue.

Mine happened after I unloaded the web project, and it defaulted to a "non-web" project as the startup project.

In order to get the browsers back I did the following:

1. Right click the web project
2. Select "Set as startup project"

This should return the browsers to the debug options.

Comment: That fixed it for me.

Comment: Before setting the StartUp project, I did not see an option to select what browser I wanted to start debugging in.

Comment: In VS2017, I had the correct project selected, but I had to switch to a different one and then back to fix the issue.

Answer (score 12):

I just ran into this same issue. In my case it was a feature.... I am working in a SharePoint App project. See the included screen shot to see where to change the browser.[image]

Comment: Wow three days of pain and it was this! Thank you David.

Comment: Is there a way to add more browsers to **Start Action** dropdown list?

Answer (score 6):

Its still there:

[image: Start with Browser in VS 2015]

with VS2015 Enterprise.

I see it in the "Standard" Toolbar, when I have loaded a Web-Solution. Not sure, which part is missing...

Use WebProject and compile as Debug:
[image]

I checked on clean Windows 7, 64bit  Professional with all Updates.
I installed VS 2015 Enterprise default Install. After this, I had only the "Start"-Option, no other browser available.

**Then** I installed Firefox 32 bit from mozilla.org, **boom** it is **"still there"** 
[image: Start with Browser in VS 2015]

I can select Firefox Or Internet Explorer.

I can not reproduce your problem, try reinstall your browser. I set [firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?scene=2#download-fx) to **default** during Installation.

Comment: I have Enterprise and I've also installed the same items as you. So it seems a problem on my machine only. I did also a reset of the VS Ui, but that didn't help as well. I will keep looking.

Comment: Tried on a second machine, same issue there. Might it be because of the OS? I'm still running Windows 7.

Comment: It's a web app don't need cordova. It's driving me crazy :-)

Comment: I have actually WebSocket4Net installed and I've tried a Repair and I have the same Buttons as you

Comment: Ok, I deleted my comments regarding WebSocket4Net because not helpful. Check my answer and reinstall browser... I Really hope that helps.

Comment: try to logon to the pc with a different user, re-install browser. Does anyone else has this Problem? I can not reproduce it with Windows 7.

Comment: I have still no solution as it seems a bug in Visual Studio but I will give you the bounty points for the effort you have taken for me. Once more thanks a lot for your Help!

Answer (score 3):

If you go to "Browse With.." and select another browser as the default this will change the Start Button to a dropdown list of the browsers like in 2013.

You can then change the Default back to IE and it will keep the dropdown list.

Answer (score 3):

After a building a new VM with win10 and VS2017 the options were not showing up while I had multiple startup projects.

[image]

Once I switched to one startup project it showed the option to choose a browser. Then after a restart my project finally launched in the browser I chose.

Comment: Good approach to open multiple projects in preferred browser.

Answer (score 2):

The list of browsers appears in the menu when the solution loaded has a single startup project. If there are multiple startup projects then the only way to change the browser is to use "Browse With..." to change the default as decribed previously.

Answer (score 0):

I've just switched to VS 2017, I couldn't see the different browsers option.
Here's what took place:

1. Just started VS2017 for the first time,
2. Couldn't see the different browsers option,
3. Didn't add, edit or remove any toolbar,
4. I had to re-set the startup project (which was my web application)
5. I had to re-set my startup page (which was an ASPX page)

And voila, the different browsers option showed up.
I'm not sure if it was step 3 or step 4 that did that, but here it was.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still missing the option for different browsers in VS2015; here is what you need to do:

1. In solution explorer,
   a. Right-click your website name
   b. Find and click 'Browse With'
   c. In the dialog box that appears
   d. Click 'Add',
   e. To the right of 'Program:' click the browse button,
   f. In the 'File name:' type the browser you want to open
   your website in and click 'Open'
   g. find and click the
   browser.exe file and click 'Open'
   h. Now the browser is added to your browsers list and you can 'Set as Default'
   or remove it, if it is not set as default.
   i. click 'Browse' and your website opens in the browser selected.
   j. now if you use the drop down menu at the top of VS2015 the browser will be   included in the list of browsers to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a co-workers development environment (Windows 7 Professional, Visual Studio 2017 15.4.2). I had him re-select Internet Explorer as the default web browser (even though it was currently selected default program).  Closed and reopened Visual Studio, and the browser options appeared correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Also check that in Solution Explorer ".Web" project is selected/focused.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,sometime if u are unable to see browsing option like IE,Chrome then follow below steps(Faced issue on - Visual studio 2015 )

```
1.Right click the web project
2.Select "Set as startup project"
```

Once you will follow above steps web browsing option will be appear.

Thanks,
Ratnesh Sahu

Answer (score -1):

Check the "debug target" option and it will be back!

[image]

Comment: please click the link above and get the screen shot.

Comment: Strangely, this worked for me in VS 2017 15.8.5. The browsers were missing so I had to fiddle around with the menu option and then suddenly the list of browsers appeared. Note the menu option was already ticked, but just by editing it and resaving without any changes, the other browsers then appeared.