# Debugging Javascript on Windows 10 with VS2015

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I upgrade my home computer to Windows 10 and installed VS2015. The default browser is edge. When I debug my project (a sharepoint hosted app), the edge browser launches and no brealpoints are hit.

How do I debug javascript on windows 10 with Vs2015?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Script checked in `Options | Debugging | Just-In-Time`.
You might also want to try running it from IE

Comment: that was checked already. Is this working for you (debugging js in windows 10 using vs2015 and edge)? How do we set up IE as the default browser for vs2015  on win 10?

Comment: If it is a SharePoint project, you should be able to change the 'start action' in the project properties section. Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606130/debugging-with-specific-browser-in-visual-studio-2015-not-possible-anymore). About mid-page there is a post related to sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you have 'just my code' enabled in your debugging options and that's causing the breakpoints to get skipped.

Go to tools -> options -> debugging and uncheck the "Just My Code" option to disable this:
[image]

And then try again.

Comment: that was unchecked already. Is this working for you (debugging js in windows 10 using vs2015 and edge)?

Comment: In most cases, yes, that's why the breakpoints aren't hit. There must be something about this project type...is it a sharepoint web part - 2010 or 2013?

Comment: Its a sharepoint hosted app (https://github.com/russgove/SPSecurity) I'm deploying to O365. On vs2013 and windows 8 I was able to just hit f5 to test and it just worked.  In my new environment I set by Default Browser too Internet Explorer, but VS2015 keeps opening the app in Edge when I hit f5.