# How to use Webbrowser Edge instead of default web browser with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, microsoft-edge

I am building new desktop solution with C# with VS 2015 and I wanna to use web browser Edge instead of the default explorer as I am getting this message: "For a better experience, update your browser"

Comment: There is a setting for this as you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606130/debugging-with-specific-browser-in-visual-studio-2015-not-possible-anymore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging with specific browser in Visual Studio 2015 not possible anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606130/debugging-with-specific-browser-in-visual-studio-2015-not-possible-anymore)

Answer (score 3):

The WinForms and WPF controls are available today as a preview in the 3.0 release of the Windows Community Toolkit in the Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls package. This means that upgrading from the Trident-powered WebBrowser control to the EdgeHTML-powered WebView in your WinForms or WPF app can be as easy as dragging in a new control from the toolbox.

**Two ways are available for adding the webview in Win Forms.**

**(1) Using the Designer:**

First, we’ll need to add a WinForms control from a NuGet package to the Toolbox in Visual Studio. In a future release, Visual Studio will do this automatically.

- First, open the Visual Studio Toolbox, then right-click anywhere in
  the toolbox, and select the Choose Items
- In the .NET Framework Components tab of the Choose Toolbox Items
  dialog box, click the Browse button to locate the
  Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.dll in your NuGet package folder.
- For help finding that folder, see Managing the global packages,
  cache, and temp folders.
- After the DLL is added to the list of Toolbox controls, WebView is
  automatically Close the Choose Toolbox Items dialog box.
- The WebView control appears in the All Windows Forms section of the
  Toolbox when the Windows Forms Designer is open.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    // You can also use the Source property here or in the designer
    webView1.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.microsoft.com"));
  }
}
```

**(2) Programmatically adding WebView:**

After installing the NuGet package, you can add the WebView to your application like any other control. The WinForms version of the control is in the Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.WinForms namespace.

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.WinForms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    // Initialize WebView and add it to the Window's controls
    var wvc = new WebView();
    ((ISupportInitialize)wvc).BeginInit();
    wvc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    Controls.Add(wvc);
    ((ISupportInitialize)wvc).EndInit();

    // You can also use the Source property
    wvc.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.microsoft.com"));
  }
}
```

Reference:

[Bringing a modern WebView to your .NET WinForms and WPF Apps](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/#2RJbfEuPmTrKOAzM.97)

Comment: Its desktop software solution not ASP web solution !
@Deepak-MSFT

Comment: Please check the updated answer and I suggest you to provide a detailed information when you ask a new question. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 , when I am trying to install Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls -Version 5.0.0   , I am getting this error: " Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls 5.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v
4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls -Version 5.0.0 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand"